# Will fruit/vegetables split with heavy constant watering?

Tags: vegetables, watering, fruits

I've heard that fruit/vegetables will split with inconsistent watering, but will it split if it can get water to its roots desires (i.e. "I go any deeper and I'll drown", or "if we get a heavy downpour my roots will cut back")? If I get enough success the first season would it be a great idea to save enough seeds for next year as I think the plant starts industry doesn't grow seed for heavier waterings (garden environment conditions of a floodplain)?

Comment: If you are trying to reinvent Lamarck's theory of evolution, don't bother. It's wrong. (Lamarck thought that, for example, if a blacksmith developed big arm muscles because of his work, his children would be *born* with bigger arm muscles than average.)

Comment: no, i'm thinking about environmental conditioning of plants through generations, similar to those who believe in human evolution with veggie seeds over years.